# Argv and argc in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I have problem with `argc`.

Command line I sent: `prog 333 jos nije kraj akademske godine`

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char pom[40];
    char *ptr;
    strcpy(pom, argv[5]+3);
    printf("%s;", pom);
    ptr=strchr(argv[6], 'd');
    printf("%s;", ptr);
    printf("%d.", argc);

    return 0;
}
```

I get `j;demske;8.`

Why is it 8 and not 7. I should get number of parameters sent.

Comment: is `prog` the first argument or the name of your program?

Comment: Did you try to print all the arguments you get?

Answer (score 1):

"akademske" is `argv[6]` so you have arguments `argv[0]` to `argv[7]`. So these are 8 arguments. `argv[0]` is the name of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the program output it seems that these sequence of wards

```
 prog 333 jos nije kraj akademske godine
```

is command line arguments. So including the program name itself that corresponds to the argv[0] `argc` is equal to `8`.

From the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by
> argv[0] represents the program name;

argv[5] is the string `kraj`. So these statements

```
strcpy(pom, argv[5]+3);
printf("%s;", pom);
```

output `'j'`.

And these statements

```
ptr=strchr(argv[6], 'd');
printf("%s;", ptr);
```

output `demske`.